# Biggest Ben in the World

Tags: internal-consistency, architecture

This is one of the modern icons of the ancient city of London...

[image]

...Big Ben Clock Tower.  It stands 320 feet tall and covers an area of 40 square feet.  Each clock face measures at a width of 23 feet, with hands varying between nine and 14 feet long.

In this alternate scenario, Big Ben is closer in size to this more modern icon...

[image]

...Abraj Al Bait in Mecca, Saudi Arabia.  It stands 1970 feet tall and covers an area of three and a half million cubic feet.  Each clock face is 151 feet wide.

With a Big Ben of that size, how loud would the hourly chime be?  (Regarding distance, not decibels.)

Comment: The size of the clock face and the loudness of the chime are independent.

Comment: You need to get information about bell towers, not clock towers. Big Ben could have chimes as loud as the mp3 player and amplifiers installed in it allow. A lot of modern clock towers are just synthesized sound.

Comment: This time I have to agree with the close votes (though I wish users would explain their votes...). I see no practical worldbuilding application in this question, merely a request for the distance at which a bell can be heard on Earth, which seems like a fairly straight-forward physics question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take the question in the spirit I imagine it was asked - suppose we scaled up the bell in Big Ben by the same amount by which the clock face was scaled, which is about six and a half. The bell of Big Ben is 9 feet in diameter and 7.5 feet tall; the bell of our Bigger Ben would then be about sixty feet across and fifty feet tall. At five hundred and seventy tons, Bigger Ben's bell would be the largest bell ever constructed, by a factor of nearly two.

Now, a quick search online turns up no hard-and-fast information on the relation between size and intensity of sound, except this: the intensity should be roughly proportional to surface area. We scaled up all our dimensions by $6.5$, so the intensity should be scaled up by $6.5^2$, roughly $42$. So Bigger Ben should be $42$ times louder than Big Ben.

Likewise, intensity should diminish with the square of distance (because the energy of the sound wave is being spread out over the surface of an expanding sphere). So Bigger Ben should be audible from about $\sqrt{42}$ times further than Big Ben, or about 6.5 times as far. I can't find any information on how far away Big Ben is audible, so I'll just assume it can be heard throughout London, which means a radius of about 22 kilometers. Bigger Ben should be audible from up to 143 kilometers away.

There's a lot of approximation and guessing here - you'd need someone more familiar with acoustics than I to get something precise.